# Android Wear: why InApp Billing check not working?

Tags: android, wear-os, in-app-billing

Dear Android Developer Community

I build right now a Wear App for my Motorola Moto. The result sould be, that the user has access to some free watch faces in Free Mode. Thru the Billing-Service of Google he can update to a Premium Version with full access. The change of the watch faces can do over a settings app on mobile phone or directly thru the settings of the watch.

So far it works everything except the Premium Check in Wear Application. Is there a difference to the normal app framework?

This example works in Mobile App Part but not in Wear App Part:

```
    // PREMIUM PART WITH STATUS CHECK (NEEDS ADDITIONAL FILES WHICH ARE NOT POSTET HERE //
    pref = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    PremiumCheck.setPremium(pref.getBoolean("ISPREMIUM", false));
    if (PremiumCheck.isPremium() == true) {

    // All things which are only visible in Premium Mode

    }   

    // FREE PART
    if (PremiumCheck.isPremium() == false ) {

    // All things which are only visible in Free Mode 

    }
```

How can I do the Premium Mode check in Wear?
What could be the solution for that?
I'm sure it's a small thing;-)

Many thanks!
Christian

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Android Wear doesn't support in-app billing. An app on the watch can't bind to `InAppBillingService`; logcat shows

```
W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent {act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND pkg=com.android.vending } U=0: not found
```

So you need to implement your IAB check on the handheld, then send some kind of message to the watch that it's been paid for.

I discussed this with a member of Google's Wear developer relations team about two months ago, and he said he'd relay the issue to the IAB folks, but there's been no further announcement since.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so far. I hope Google accelerating the wear development even further. It's a good product. For my case, I try to make the check in the settings part for the moment or sell the app without inapp.